# Retrieving the newest X amount of entries in a MYSQl database, with Node-MYSQL? Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-mysql

I am able to retrieve the latest entry in node-mysql with:

```
connection.query('SELECT * FROM NewsV2 ORDER BY IDCode DESC LIMIT 1',  
  function(err, rows, fields) {}
```

But, I would like to retrieve the latest say ten entries, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a column for date, you would add that to the query
`ORDER BY IDCode DESC Date DESC`  and if you want 10, change the limit to 10 `LIMIT 10`.

If IDCode isnt the id col, and you happen to be adding new rows at a time, you can also add the sort `ORDER BY ID DESC`  but ill guess your IDCode is your ID field.